# ActionController::UrlGenerationError con ActionMailer al intentar mostrar un enlace

Tags: ruby-on-rails

¿Qué tal?, bueno les cuento, llevo un tiempo trabajando con Rails y ActiveAdmin, no he tenido mayores inconvenientes, no soy un experto ni nada, pero existe bastante ayuda en Internet que puede ayudar a resolver bastantes dudas.

En mi aplicación estoy creando mantenciones para equipos industriales, simplemente selecciono una tarea, asigno un técnico(admin_user) y selecciono una fecha para el inicio del mantenimiento. Estoy implementando el envío de una notificación que llegará a la cuenta de email del técnico(admin_user) seleccionado para el mantenimiento con los detalles asociados al mantenimiento creado por el formulario de ActiveAdmin.

A continuación dejo los detalles de la codificación.

**app/models/maintenance.rb**

```
class Maintenance < ApplicationRecord

  extend Enumerize
  enumerize :state, in: [:pendiente, :en_curso, :finalizado, :cancelado], default: :pendiente

  include AASM

  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :admin_user

  aasm column: 'state' do
    state :pendiente, initial: true
    state :en_curso, :finalizado, :cancelado

    event :aceptar do
      transitions from: :pendiente, to: :en_curso
    end

    event :finalizar do
      transitions from: :en_curso, to: :finalizado
    end

    event :cancelar do
      transitions from: [:pendiente, :en_curso]
    end
  end

end
```

**app/admin/admin_maintenances.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Maintenance, as: 'Mantenimiento' do

permit_params :task_id, :admin_user_id, :created_at, :state, :end

form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      if !f.object.new_record?
        f.li do
          f.label 'Tarea'
          f.span f.object.task
        end
      else
        f.input :task, label: 'Tarea'
    end

      f.input :admin_user, as: :select, collection: AdminUser.where(role: 'tecnico'), label: 'Técnico'
      f.input :created_at, as: :date_time_picker, label: 'Inicio mantenimiento', class: 'input-date-time', hint: 'Fecha y hora en la que se realizará el mantenimiento.'
      f.input :end, as: :date_time_picker, label: 'Fin mantenimiento', class: 'input-date-time', hint: 'Si el mantenimiento tiene una duración de varios días.'
      f.actions
    end
  end

  controller do

    def create
    @maintenance = Maintenance.new(permitted_params[:maintenance])
      super do |format|
        MaintenanceMailer.nuevo_mantenimiento(@maintenance).deliver
        redirect_to admin_mantenimiento_url(@mantenimiento) and return if resource.valid?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**app/mailers/maintenance_mailer.rb**

```
class MaintenanceMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'info@example.cl'

  def nuevo_mantenimiento(maintenance)
    @maintenance = maintenance
    mail(to: @maintenance.admin_user.email, subject: 'Nuevo mantenimiento')
  end
end
```

**app/views/maintenance_mailer/nuevo_mantenimiento.html.erb**

```
<h2>Hola, ha sido creado un nuevo mantenimiento.</h2>

<h3>Técnico asignado: <%= link_to @maintenance.admin_user.nombre, admin_admin_user_url(@maintenance.admin_user.id) %></h3>

  <ul>
    <li>Equipo: <%= @maintenance.task.equipment.nombre %></li>
    <li>Modelo: <%= @maintenance.task.equipment.modelo %></li>
    <li>Ubicacion: <%= @maintenance.task.equipment.ubicacion.presence || "No especificado" %></li>
    <li>Inicio mantenimiento: <%= l(@maintenance.created_at, format: :long) %></li>
    <li>Estado inicial: [<%= @maintenance.state %>]</li>
  </ul>

  <p>Más detalles <%= link_to @maintenance.task.equipment.nombre, admin_mantenimiento_url(@maintenance) %> </p>
```

Estoy generando una vista previa del email con **ActionMailer Preview**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aquí, todo marcha bien, la vista previa me genera el enlace del técnico asignado y del mantenimiento correspondiente el cual muestra el nombre del equipo y otorga el enlace tipo: localhost:3000/admin/mantenimientos/70

El problema surge cuando realizo esto enviando el formulario del mantenimiento, me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Esto ocurre sólo con el enlace correspondiente a el mantenimiento**, si quito el enlace, el email se envía e incluso me da el enlace que muestra el técnico asignado sin ningún inconveniente.

¿De qué me estoy perdiendo?

Quedo atento a las respuestas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en _app/admin/admin_maintenances.rb_:

```
def create
  @maintenance = Maintenance.new(permitted_params[:maintenance])

  super do |format|
    MaintenanceMailer.nuevo_mantenimiento(@maintenance).deliver
    redirect_to admin_mantenimiento_url(@mantenimiento) and return if resource.valid?
  end
end
```

Estás creando una instancia nueva de `Maintenance` pero no la estás guardando, por lo tanto no existe un `id` en el objeto que envías a `MaintenanceMailer` (resultando en `id: nil`).

Para corregirlo puedes utilizar `@maintenance.save` después de crear el objeto o utilizar `create` en lugar de `new`; yo me inclinaría por utilizar `save` ya que así puedes validar que el el objeto se haya creado correctamente antes de continuar; por ejemplo:

```
def create
  @maintenance = Maintenance.new(permitted_params[:maintenance])

  if @maintenance.save
    MaintenanceMailer.nuevo_mantenimiento(@maintenance).deliver
    redirect_to admin_mantenimiento_url(@mantenimiento) and return if resource.valid?
  else
    # redirect a página donde se crea el objeto. 
  end
end
```

Con esto estás definiendo la acción `create` fuera de *ActiveAdmin*, por lo que es importante eliminar `super` para evitar que se duplique la creación del objeto.

Comment: Cuando utilizo @maintenance.id aparece **No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/mantenimientos", :id=>nil}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]**

Comment: La única forma que he conseguido para mostrar el id es pasar en admin_mantenimiento_url(**Maintenance.last**), pero veo que es una opción muy limitada.

Comment: @MosiahRicardo Tienes razón, me equivoqué en el diagnóstico del error, el problema está en que no has guardado la instancia `@maintenance` y, por lo tanto, no se ha generado un `id`. Mira la respuesta actualizada para ver como solucionarlo.

Comment: Realice la modificación del archivo como me mencionaste en la respuesta, se crea el mantenimiento y envía el email con la información, pero se están creando dos mantenimientos a la vez.

Comment: @MosiahRicardo Podrías evitar que se guarden dos mantenimientos si quitas `super do` (pues ahí se llama a `create` nuevamente sobre el objeto); he actualizado otra vez la respuesta.

Comment: Todo funcionando, eternamente agradecido.